# Unable to call refresh() or any of View class methods on created instance

Tags: javascript, extjs, auto-update

In my ExtJS 4.0 app, I have a view already created and initialized, but from one of my controllers, I'm trying to update it using `refresh()` after creating its instance within controller.

```
//Following code is within a controller.
var myView = this.getView('MyView').create();
console.log(myView); //this logs entire Map with methods and other members.
myView.refresh(); //doesn't work.
```

Basically, the logged `myView` object shows that data within the store is updated, but same is not reflected on the page, hence I tried calling `refresh()` on View object, but that throws an error saying that method is undefined.

What's wrong here?

P.S.: I'm new to ExtJS.

Comment: Did you try to call `load()` on store? Your view should reflect changes in store automatically.

Comment: @Eugene: I'm dealing with app not originally coded by me, do I look for/or call `load()` within View file?

Comment: If your view extends Ext.grid.Panel you should be able to run myView.getStore().load()

Comment: @Eugene: It extends `Ext.container.Container`. :/

Comment: So it means that you have some element in `items` of `MyView` that displays the data?

Comment: @Eugene: Ya, and those items are of different `xtype`. The view loads correct data on first load, but doesn't update on UI upon selection of different items, while logging the object internally shows presence of updated data.

Answer (score 0):

This may happen if your view is not rendered yet. Try this:

```
myView.on('afterrender', function (self) { 
    self.refresh() 
});
```